# Minimal audio (wav or mp3) file in bytes for unit testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to find a minimal audio file (like the `testfile_gif` below) for unit testing.

I don't want to load it from the hard drive (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4287271/2275286)).

I want the second test to perform like the first one.

```py
import magic
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile


class TestFiles(TestCase):
    def test_working(self):
        # Test an Image File #
        testfile_gif = (
            b'\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x21\xf9\x04'
            b'\x01\x0a\x00\x01\x00\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02'
            b'\x02\x4c\x01\x00\x3b')
        gif_file = SimpleUploadedFile(name='image.gif', content=testfile_gif,
                                      content_type='image/gif')
        mime = magic.from_buffer(gif_file.read(1024), mime=True)
        self.assertEqual('image/gif', mime)

    def test_not_working(self):
        # Test an Audio File #
        testfile_audio = b'What should be written in here?'
        audio_file = SimpleUploadedFile(name='music.mp3',
                                        content=testfile_audio,
                                        content_type='audio/mpeg')
        mime = magic.from_buffer(audio_file.read(1024), mime=True)
        self.assertEqual('audio/mpeg', mime)
```

Preferably, I don't want to use any packages (like `import mock`).

**UPDATE**

Here is an `mp3` file with `audio/mpeg` mime:

```
b'MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x03\x01\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
b'\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x11\x00\x03'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: That is not a MP3 file, `MM\x00*` is the magic for TIFF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple .wav file. You can make these with python quite easily using the [wave](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) module.

```
b'RIFF$\x00\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00data\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: This nicely works for my unit testing purposes. The content type of this is `audio\x-wav`.