# How to create an object that has an ImageField within the test code?

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, backend

I'm creating something like a blog post, the blog post can contain multiple images. To be able to include a variable number of images, I created a new model called `Image`. This model contains a `ForeignKey` to the user that owns it, and an `ImageField`.

Code:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_upload_path)
```

In the post model, I have a `ManyToManyField` for the `Image` model. this way, I can have a variable number of images.

```
images = models.ManyToManyField('Image', blank=True)
```

I'm trying to test my code. In one of the tests, I'm trying to create a couple of images, then create a post with the images being passed to in a list.

How do I create an instance of the model `Image` within the tests and provide it an image?

```
image = Image.objects.create(user=self.user, image=...)
```

What should be written instead of `...` here?

Comment: This [answer by Mirko Rossini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4287271/14991864) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide the path the image file you are going to use for testing. Here is how I have done it.

```
image = Image.objects.create(user=self.user,image='path/to/file.png')
```