# How to create test for UserProfile form in django

Tags: django, forms, testcase

I'm new to Django and I'm nor sure what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to run tests for my form "UserProfileForm" and the test fails all time and I don't know why. Can anyone help?

this is my forms.py

```
from .models import UserProfile
from dobwidget import DateOfBirthWidget


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'profile_img',
            'subscribe',
            'bio',
            'dob',
            'telephone',
            'contact_by_phone',
            'contact_by_email'
            ]
        widgets = {
            'dob': DateOfBirthWidget(),
        }
```

this is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class UserProfile(models.Model):


    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default="images/default_profile.png")
    subscribe = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8, null=True, blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    contact_by_phone = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    contact_by_email = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And this is the test that I'm trying to run

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .forms import UserProfileForm



class TestUserProfileForm(TestCase):


    def test_can_create_a_profile(self):
        valid_data = {
            'profile_img':"images/perfil.jpg", 
            'subscribe':False, 
            'bio':'asdjklsad asdkj;s', 
            'dob':'2019-03-03',
            'telephone' : '12324',
            'contact_by_phone' : True,
            'contact_by_email' : True,
        }
        form = UserProfileForm(data=valid_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Comment: Is there any error/exception message?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, the `profile_img` needs to be an instance of a file-like object

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20508664/3452345

Comment: Thanks  but I have tried what you said and test is still not passing.. Is this the right way?

Comment: profile_image = SimpleUploadedFile('images/default_profile.png', b"file_content", content_type="image/png")     and after assign it to 'profile_img' ?     'profile_img':profile_image,